# C++ heap corruption detected occurs while I try to use the function I made in derived class

Tags: c++

Here comes my code. Firstly I have defined the three class

`class matrix {protected:
        double *mdata;
        int rows,columns;`

`class polyg{protected: matrix x,y,z,centre;`

`class triangle: public polyg{protected:public:
    triangle(matrix x1,matrix y1,matrix z1){x=x1;y=y1;z=z1;
    centre=(x+y+z).change_scale(1/3);
    }`

and I have defined a overloading function for matrix multiplication such as

```
matrix operator*(matrix &m) const{
  if(columns!=m.getrows()) {
      cout<<"invalid size!!"<<endl; exit(1);
  }
  matrix temp(rows,m.getcols());
  for(int x=0; x<rows; x++) {
      for(int y=0; y<m.getcols(); y++) {
          double value = 0;
          for(int z=0; z<columns; z++) {
              value = value+(mdata[index(x+1,z+1)]*m.mdata[index(z+1,y+1)]);
          }
          temp.mdata[index(x+1,y+1)] = value;
      } 
  }
  return temp;}
```

index function is defined as

```
int index(int m, int n) const // Return position in array of element (m,n){
if(m>0 && m<=rows && n>0 && n<=columns) return (n-1)+(m-1)*columns;
else {cout<<"Error: out of range"<<endl; exit(1);}
```

}

and I defined member function, which overrides the pure virtual function in polyg class, in triangle class such as

```
    void rotate(double angle){

double pi=4*atan(1.0);
double angle_rad=pi*angle/180;

matrix m_rot(2,2);
m_rot(1,1)=cos(angle_rad);
m_rot(1,2)=sin(angle_rad);
m_rot(2,2)=cos(angle_rad);
m_rot(2,1)=-sin(angle_rad);//matrix of rotation of angle inserted

x=m_rot*x;
y=m_rot*y;
z=m_rot*z;//rotating the triangle

}
```

problem occurs from

```
x=m_rot*x;
y=m_rot*y;
z=m_rot*z;
```

this part. Heap corruption detected error occurs from this part. if I remove this part, code runs totally well without any problem.

Also, if I define in main

```
int main(){matrix a,b,c; c=a*b;
```

it works totally well also.

however if I use the function I made in triangle class,for example,

```
triangle tri(a,b,c); tri.rotate(30);
```

problem occurs

no errors occur before the debugging 
but after I compile,
Heap Corruption detected error occurs

could someone explain what is the problem? and how to fix it?

Comment: This example is not complete. Is it minimal?

Comment: I edited slightly and added more details. Have a look

Comment: You need to remove details.

Comment: why is that? Sorry I am using this web site for first time.

Comment: A lot of cruft around the core issue makes it harder to understand the issue.  Heap corruption has nothing to do with polygons, so try paring it down to where you think the error occurs.  Usually this is due to you stomping on memory by writing past the end of a buffer.

Comment: Ok I will try to fix the contents.

Comment: Include the constructor, destructor and _copy constructor_ for matrix.

Comment: Can you please post the entire matrix class?

Comment: I added the entire matrix class. thanks.

Comment: if anyone need whole cpp file, then I could send the file via email. I am quite urgent with this programming so..

Comment: I think your line "x,y,z,centre=a;" should be "x = y = z = centre=a;", otherwise, x,y and z are undefined.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but still Heap Corruption detected error occurs. thanks anyway.

Comment: one thing I found is if I remove the delete [] mdata from destructor in matrix, it works without error but it gives weird value

Comment: This code is still not complete, and I really doubt it's minimal -- by which I mean you should *simplify* the code as much as you can, while still producing the error. Preparing a minimal complete example is a very useful skill, and if you neglect it we have to do a lot of extra work.

Comment: Post your solution rather than editing the question body to say that its fixed.

Comment: matrix operator*(matrix &m) const{//multiplication
    if(columns!=m.getrows()) {
    cout<<"invalid size!!"<<endl; exit(1);
    }
    matrix temp(rows,m.getcols());
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++) {
     for(int y=0; y<m.getcols(); y++) {
     double value = 0;
      for(int z=0; z<columns; z++) {
      value = value+mdata[index(x+1,z+1)]*m.mdata[m.index(z+1,y+1)];
      }
     temp.mdata[m.index(x+1,y+1)] = value;
     } 
    }
   return temp;
   } this is the corrected version. The problem was caused from writting m.mdata[index(z+1,y+1)] rather than m.mdata[m.index(z+1,y+1)].

Comment: Also I changed the question so that it can be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks suspect to me:

```
 for(int x=0; x<rows; x++) {
      for(int y=0; y<m.getcols(); y++) {
          double value = 0;
          for(int z=0; z<columns; z++) {
              value = value+(mdata[index(x+1,z+1)]*m.mdata[index(z+1,y+1)]);
          }
          temp.mdata[index(x+1,y+1)] = value;
```

With `z` you are iterating over column indexes, but you pass that value as the first argument to the `index` function (source now no longer present in your post) which appears to assume that the first argument is always a row index.

Comment: Agreed - anytime I see "index+1" type code in a for loop, it's ripe for array overruns and future malloc failures.

Comment: here is the definition of index function:                            int index(int m, int n) const // Return position in array of element (m,n)
  {
    if(m>0 && m<=rows && n>0 && n<=columns) return (n-1)+(m-1)*columns;
    else {cout<<"Error: out of range"<<endl; exit(1);}
  }

Comment: Where is temp.mdata defined?

Comment: class matrix 
{
protected:
  double *mdata;
  int rows,columns;